# Xamarin shared resources : Global Styles and Markup Extensions

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there an advantage to using a `XAML Markup Extension` instead of a `Style` tag at the application (or page) level when setting global properties?

Context:

In the "XAML Basics" [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions) they give the following example:

```xml
ORIGINAL

 <Button Text="Do this!"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                BorderWidth="3"
                Rotation="-15"
                TextColor="Red"
                FontSize="24" />

... OTHER SIMILAR BUTTONS ...

CLEAN

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <LayoutOptions x:Key="horzOptions"
                       Alignment="Center" />

        <LayoutOptions x:Key="vertOptions"
                       Alignment="Center"
                       Expands="True" />

         <x:Double x:Key="borderWidth">
            3
         </x:Double>

        <x:Double x:Key="rotationAngle">-15</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Button Text="Do this!"
        HorizontalOptions="{StaticResource horzOptions}"
        VerticalOptions="{StaticResource vertOptions}"
        BorderWidth="{StaticResource borderWidth}"
        Rotation="{StaticResource rotationAngle}"
        TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource fontSize}" />
```

and in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) for Style they give the following example:

```xml
RESOURCE DICTIONARY CONTAINING BUTTON STYLE set in App.cs
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Teal" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

BUTTON WITH STYLE APPLIED IN A ContentPage

<Button Text="These buttons" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
```

Clearly they are syntactically similar but the second one is much less verbose, so what's the point of the first approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Obviously**, they are different definitions according to the document.

**XAML Markup Extensions**

> XAML markup extensions constitute an important feature in XAML that allow properties to be set to objects or values that are referenced indirectly from other sources. XAML markup extensions are particularly important for sharing objects, and referencing constants used throughout an application, but they find their greatest utility in data bindings.

**Global Styles in Xamarin.Forms**

> Styles can be made available globally by adding them to the application's resource dictionary. This helps to avoid duplication of styles across pages or controls.

You will see that the range of ***XAML Markup Extensions*** is greater than ***Global Styles***,
however ***Global Styles*** is just a special use for ***Styles*** of ***Resource***.